# Finding period of a sequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computer-science, number-theory, period

I want to solve this problem:

For a given sequence, `a[0], a[1], a[2],..., a[n-1]`, please find "period" of the sequence.
The period is the minimum integer k (k >= 1) that satisfies a[i] = a[i+k] for all valid i, and also k is a divisor of n.

My current solution is calculating all divisor of n (this is k) and test for all k, but it takes `O(n * d(n))`. I think it is slow.
Is there any efficient algorithm?

Comment: You could exclude some of the divisors with O(1) rather than O(n). If a[0] !== a[1] you exclude divisor 1. If a[0] !== a[2] you exclude divisor 2. If a[0] !== a[3] you exclude divisor 3 etc. In general if a[0] !== a[divisor] you can exclude divisor from potential solutions.

Comment: @FreemanLambda but that test can pass even if the tested divisor isn't the period, so I disagree that it's O(1). It *might* reject the divisor in one step, but it can also be much later.

Comment: @harold what you say is true, but in his current solution square1001 is always testing every divisor (until solution found). Assuming that there is already a loop in place that finds all divisors of n, it shouldn't be that costly to just sneak in the a[0] !== a[divisor] in that loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply Z-algorithm ( [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/z-algorithm-linear-time-pattern-searching-algorithm/) and [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107?locale=ru)) to given sequence.

Then find the first position `i` such that

```
  i+z[i] = n
```

and

```
  n mod i = 0
```

If such value of `i` exists, it is the shortest period